# In Matlab: How to create a 2d map from a 3 columns file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Relatively new to Matlab, I've been tryin to create a 2d map from a 3 columns file (x coord, y coord, value of cell (x,y)) but not sure how to proceed.

For example:

```
1901 0 1
1901 -10 2
1901 -20 3
1902 0 -1
1902 -10 3.5
1902 -20 1.5
1903 0 5
1903 -10 -3
1903 -20 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What's the desired output in your example?

Answer (score 0):

The map you are referring to is called a weighted histogram, in this case a 2D one.

so, if your data is `d`:

```
d=[1901 0 1
   1901 -10 2
   1901 -20 3
   1902 0 -1
   1902 -10 3.5
   1902 -20 1.5
   1903 0 5
   1903 -10 -3
   1903 -20 0];
```

you can use the [following 2d weighted histogram from the FEX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46012-2d-weighted-histogram). then simply write:

```
xbins=min(d(:,1)):max(d(:,1));
ybins=min(d(:,2)):max(d(:,2));

H = hist2w([d(:,1) , d(:,2)],d(:,3),xbins,ybins);
imagesc(ybins,xbins,H)
colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply bla! Is there a way to have the final figure look more like a 'heatmap' (ie not an histogram)?

Comment: not sure I understand what is your desired output here. You can always change the colormap to some other colors.